# Error when I try to install Bugzilla on windows server

Tags: bugzilla, windows-server

I am trying to install Bugzilla on my windows server. I am using Strawberry Perl & PostgreSQL. But when I run the website, I got an error like:

```
Software error:
'Pg' is not a valid choice for $db_driver in  localconfig: Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.xs.dll' for module DBD::Pg: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
 at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 30.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 30.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 30.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 138) line 2.


For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error. 
[Mon Nov 17 16:34:41 2014] config.cgi: 'Pg' is not a valid choice for $db_driver in localconfig: Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.xs.dll' for module DBD::Pg: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193. [Mon Nov 17 16:34:41 2014] config.cgi: at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 30. [Mon Nov 17 16:34:41 2014] config.cgi: Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 30. [Mon Nov 17 16:34:41 2014] config.cgi: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 30. [Mon Nov 17 16:34:41 2014] config.cgi: Compilation failed in require at (eval 138) line 2.
```

I have run the checksetup.pl. All modules are installed. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your PATH includes the Pg bin directory.